# Problem with bind_rows: Error: Argument 1 must have names

Tags: r, rows, bind

I have two data frames and I need to put the line of my second data frame as the last line of my first data frame:

The first data frame is PETR3.SA:

```
tail(PETR3.SA)
           PETR3.SA.Open PETR3.SA.High PETR3.SA.Low PETR3.SA.Close
2020-04-23      17.35522      17.63133     16.85232       17.09884
2020-04-24      16.86218      17.01009     15.30415       15.84650
2020-04-27      16.14233      16.68468     15.74789       16.56635
2020-04-28      17.49000      18.02000     17.11000       18.02000
2020-04-29      18.51000      19.30000     18.35000       19.00000
2020-04-30      18.73000      19.18000     18.43000       18.65000
           PETR3.SA.Volume PETR3.SA.Adjusted
2020-04-23        19498900          17.09884
2020-04-24        39716700          15.84650
2020-04-27        25446600          16.56635
2020-04-28        24004700          18.02000
2020-04-29        26938000          19.00000
2020-04-30        23209200          18.65000

str(PETR3.SA)
An ‘xts’ object on 2015-01-02/2020-04-30 containing:
  Data: num [1:1322, 1:6] 9.07 8.18 7.84 7.86 8.15 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "PETR3.SA.Open" "PETR3.SA.High" "PETR3.SA.Low" "PETR3.SA.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 3
 $ src      : chr "yahoo"
 $ updated  : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2020-05-04 17:14:02"
 $ na.action: 'omit' int [1:3] 779 1038 1281
  ..- attr(*, "index")= num [1:3] 1.52e+09 1.55e+09 1.58e+09
```

My second df:

```
cotacao_xts
           PETR3.SA.Open PETR3.SA.High PETR3.SA.Low PETR3.SA.Close
2020-05-04         19.02         19.02        19.02          19.02
           PETR3.SA.Volume PETR3.SA.Adjusted
2020-05-04               0             19.02
> str(cotacao_xts)
An ‘xts’ object on 2020-05-04/2020-05-04 containing:
  Data: num [1, 1:6] 19 19 19 19 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "PETR3.SA.Open" "PETR3.SA.High" "PETR3.SA.Low" "PETR3.SA.Close" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
```

**I need to put my second df (cotacao_xts) as the last line of my first df.**

I tried bind_rows, but this is what I got:

```
> new_df <- PETR3.SA %>%
+   bind_rows(cotacao_xts)
Error: Argument 1 must have names
```

Comment: It  is not a data.frame, but a `xts` object

Comment: You may use `rbind`

Answer (score 1):

As these are `xts` objects, we can use `rbind` assuming the index are unique

```
library(xts)
rbind(PETR3.SA, cotacao_xts)
```

---

```
methods(class = 'xts')[50]
#[1] "rbind.xts"
```

---

According to `?bind_rows`

> ... - Data frames to combine

It can be `data.table`, `data.frame` or `tbl_df`.  The `xts` object is neither one of those.  It is a `matrix` with `xts` attribute.  If we need to use `bind_rows`, then the objects needs to be converted to `data.frame`